# How to use TestStack.White to click the button under the menu

Tags: c#, ui-automation

[image]I tried to use [white](https://github.com/TestStack/White) to click the new project button, I try using the below code, but it can not work, anyone can help me?

```
 public void Notepad()
        {
            Application app = Application.Launch("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SourceMonitor\\SourceMonitor.exe");
            Window window = app.GetWindow("SourceMonitor", InitializeOption.NoCache);

            Button button = window.Get<Button>("File");
            button.Click();


            app.Kill();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I already figured out how to do it, below is the correct code:

```
 public void Notepad()
        {
            // Arrange
            Application app = Application.Launch("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SourceMonitor\\SourceMonitor.exe");
            Window window = app.GetWindow("SourceMonitor", InitializeOption.NoCache);

            // Act

            MenuBar menuBar = window.MenuBar;
            menuBar.MenuItem("File","New Project").Click(); ; //can use any other search criteria as well.
}
```